# how to change background color of the select box on select2 (bootstrap theme)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

the javascript ofc

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
            theme: "bootstrap-5"
          });
       });
```

the HTML

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single bg-dark" style="background-color: #343a40 !         important;" name ="state"></select>
```

Its missing just around the block, here's what it currently looks like. I just cant find the tag name to change the background color.

[image: its missing just around the block, heres what it currently looks like. i just cant find the tag name to change the background color]

Comment: Hit F12 (developer tools) in your browser. That will help you find the tag name (html element). You can also apply css rules right there and see any changes live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the tag name of an element in your HTML document, you can inspect it using the browser's developer tools. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open your webpage in a browser.
2. Right-click on the element whose tag name you want to find.
3. Select "Inspect" or "Inspect Element" from the context menu. This will open the browser's developer tools.
4. In the HTML panel of the developer tools, you will see the selected element highlighted. The tag name of the element will be displayed at the beginning of the highlighted line.
   Alternatively, you can hover over the element in the Elements panel of the developer tools, and the tag name will be displayed in a tooltip.

Once you've identified the tag name, you can use it to target the element using jQuery or any other method for modifying its styles or properties.

Comment: i was trying this but just couldnt find it. i guess it was in the code that select2 generates. thanks!